# read() with setsockopt() in C

Tags: c, setsockopt

I'm trying to write a server-client code and I'm stuck at a point. I want the client to read for a certain amount of time and timeout. I tried using setsockopt() with SO_RCVTIMEO specifying the time in timeval struct, but my read() doesn't wait for the time I specify in timeval struct. 
Thing is, read() is waiting for the specified time if I just use read() after setsockopt(). If I first call write() and then read(), the read() function times-out immediately without waiting for the specified time as given in timeval struct. 
My code is shown below:

//sample client code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/socket.h>
    #include<netinet/in.h>
    #include<netdb.h>


    void error(char *msg)
    {
        perror(msg);
        exit(1);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int a=1;
        fd_set readfds,writefds;
        int ready_for_reading,reading;
        struct timeval time_out;

        int sockfd,newsockfd,portno,n;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        struct hostent *server;
    //  server=gethostbyname(argv[1]);
        char buffer[256];
        portno=atoi(argv[2]);
        sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        server=gethostbyname(argv[1]);
        serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);
        bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
            (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            server->h_length);
        time_out.tv_sec = 15;    // 15 seconds
            time_out.tv_usec = 0;    // 0 milliseconds

    //  sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        if(sockfd==-1)
            error("\nError creating socket");
    //      if(setsockopt (sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&time_out, sizeof (time_out)))
    //               error("\n\tsetsockopt function has a problem\n");

        n=connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
        if(n==-1)
            error("\nError connecting to server");
        printf("\nEnter client's msg:");
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        n=write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if(n<0)
            error("\nMsg not written to server");
        if(setsockopt (sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&time_out, sizeof(time_out)))
            error("\n\tsetsockopt function has a problem\n");

    //  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    //  FD_SET(sockfd,&readfds);

        n=read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    //  ready_for_reading=select(sockfd,&readfds,NULL,NULL,&time_out);
    //  printf("\nready_for_reading=%d",ready_for_reading);
    /*  if (ready_for_reading)
            {
              //  reading = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
                printf("Read, %d bytes from input : %s \n", n,buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" 10 Seconds are over - no data input \n");
                return 0;
            }
    */
        if(n<0)
            printf("\nMsg not read from server");
        if(n==0)
        {
            printf("\n No ack from server");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("\nServer's ack:%s\n",buffer);

    /*  if (ready_for_reading) 
        {
            //  reading = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
                printf("Read, %d bytes from input : %s \n", n,buffer);
            } 
        else 
        {
                    printf(" 10 Seconds are over - no data input \n");
            return 0;
            }
    */
        return 0;
    }
```

In my code above, I want the read() operation to timeout in 15secs. But it times-out immediately. I need help!!!

Comment: Does the read return a negative value?

Comment: no.. the read() returns '0' which i guess means '0' bytes read...

Comment: Have you checked if after `setsockop` `errno` has been set?

Answer (score 1):

If `read` returns zero, that means the connection is closed. There is nothing to wait for, so it cannot wait.

Also, this code is broken:

```
    printf("\nServer's ack:%s\n",buffer);
```

You can only use the `%s` format specifier to print a C-style string. The way you've used it, there is no way it could know how many bytes to print because that's only held in the variable `n` at this point in your code.

Comment: ohk.. thanks a lot David for pointing that out.. I was closing the connection on the server side.. now it works.. :)

Comment: @Richard: Make sure to fix the other bug, otherwise it's only working by luck.